# Using a tbone SC 420 USB mic on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, sound, 20.04, microphone

I'm trying to use a tbone SC 420 USB mic on Ubuntu 20.04, but I can't get it to record anything. The mic appears in sound settings, but never picks up any noise.

This is its entry in `proc`:

```sh
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x2ffb028000 irq 168
 1 [MICROPHONE     ]: USB-Audio - USB MICROPHONE
                      USB MICROPHONE USB MICROPHONE at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, full speed
```

and I think the kernel modules are OK (and other microphones seem fine):

```sh
$ lsmod |grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   122880  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_usb_audio         262144  3
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,thinkpad_acpi
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

but the device doesn't seem to appear in `lsusb`:

```sh
$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:2115 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 24f0:0137  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 3212:1a03  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:0000 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Optical mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There are some errors in `dmesg` which look suspicious:

```sh
$ dmesg | grep error | less
[    3.983808] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    4.597568] usb 1-2.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  955.731572] usb 1-2.3: clear tt 1 (9092) error -71
[  955.731647] usb 1-2.3: clear tt 1 (9092) error -71
# Lots more error -71
```

but it's not really clear to me whether these are related.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can record via a tbone SC 420 USB mic on Ubuntu 20.04. But as soon as the USB cable of this microphone is attached, my Laptop does not play sound any more. The audio quality is good. But I need working audio output, too.

Comment: Possibly the output is going to the line out of the microphone?

Comment: I changed the output sink to PC via Ubuntu settings. There must be something broken internally.

Comment: Ah right. The one I bought had a broken mute button, and I had to get it replaced, but the process was very straightforward. Good luck!

Comment: @snim2 Could you add output of `pactl list cards; pactl list sources; pactl list sinks;` . A complete would be `alsa-info` . Did you try `alsamixer` change card.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it turned out that the microphone itself was faulty!